# All browsers redirect me to the wrong site

Tags: networking, windows-8, browser, virus

I'm trying to reach www.example.com, but I'm always get redirect by all browsers to www.anothersite.com (from any other computer www.example.com is perfectly reachable), which most likely a virus, although my antivirus can't catch it.

I already checked hosts file, there is nothing in it, is there anything else I can do to figure out the problem?

P.S. And it happens only with "example.com" (visiting other sites does not redirect)

**Edit**

The site in question is `siliconrus.com`
On my machine, it redirects to `top-shop.ru`, but this forwarding does not occur for other people.

The same issues persists in safe mode.

Comment: What is the site in question? Do you know if this issue is only happening to you or any browser from any machine?

Comment: The site is siliconrus.com and it is redirected to top-shop.ru. The former is famous blog about startups, the latter is some jitney online shop. The point is that siliconrus.com won't do this on purpose and I've contacted them and they said they are ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit 2**

Based upon your comments, I think this may be malware and not a virus - use MalwareBytes and perform a scan

---

**EDIT**

As per your edit, since it only happens with one site, then it's that 1 site. They have put a forwarder on I assume.

---

Original answer below

I think you should start the browser in safe mode because this disables all plug ins which is most likely cause (assuming it's not a virus as per your virus check)

If it works fine in safe mode, you need to start bringing the plugins in, one at a time to find the culprit.

Comment: Do you mean Private mode? If you do, I've already tried it, nothing

Comment: @colix, updated my answer

Comment: MalwareBytes solved the issue, thank you very much!